# How to combine python and C++17 on macOS

Tags: python, macos, c++17

I'm currently working on a project that combines C++ and python on macOS, so at some point my code includes the system python header:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
```

I would like to switch to C++17, but one of the headers (`unicodeobject.h`) included by `Python.h` still uses the `register` keyword that was removed in C++17 after being deprecated in C++11.

Are there any suggestions on if and how I can make the move to C++17 in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use

```
#define register
```

before you include `<Python.h>` to define the `register` macro to expand to nothing. Alternatively, you can use the command line option `-Dregister=`.

Strictly speaking, modern versions of the C++ standard make it invalid to use the preprocessor to define the meaning of a standard keyword differently, but your compiler may accept it anyway (or at most, give a warning).

Comment: That works, but I was hoping there's a way to avoid the preprocessor "hack"